# Is throwing malicious strings in json_encode a good way to evade Stored XSS?

Tags: xss

I'm aware that filtering strings doesn't go this way, but when encoding xss payloads into json format in php and storing that information temporary in classes,  the result in the browser, it will show all the strings that are before the javascript content, the payload in the middle won't execute since i use `json_encode` for all the strings and all what is after the javascript content is not displayed in the browser. but can i use this in real world applications?

[image]

I use a picture to read with more comfortability

Comment: Please include your code as text snippet.

Comment: +Samuel Philipp But if i do that it will create confusion in the last line, the colors show the diffrence

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about, can you clarify? :)

Comment: Seems like this same question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062146/is-json-encode-sufficient-xss-protection. Can't mark this question a duplicate because it's in another stack exchange forum.

Comment: @Artog I want to know if it is a stable/secure method to plague attackers in the sense if the effect is similar to sanitizing, while it is not a method at all.